# How to get component of gameobjects in a list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have this script to add my selected gameobjects to a list (in runtime).

```
public Transform ParentOfList;
public List<GameObject> Objects3d = new List<GameObject>();
public GameObject ActualSelected;

public void add3DtoList()
{
    foreach (Transform child in ParentOfList) // iterate through all first level children
    {
        if (child.gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            Debug.Log($"The child {child.name} is active!");
            ActualSelected = child.gameObject;
            if (Objects3d.Contains(ActualSelected))
            {
                Debug.Log("Already exist in list");
            }
            else
            {
                Objects3d.Add(ActualSelected); //add the actual gameobject selected in runtime to list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PD: the parent gameobject only have one child active at the same time.

each gameobject added to the list have a text component, I want to get these individual text component from the list and put it in a new variable text.
Like:

```
Text MergeText;
MergeText.text = ListIndex1.text + ListIndex2.text + etc;
```

I don't know how implement this. Some guidance?, thanks.

**SOLVED,**
**Script one List:**

```
public Transform ParentOfList;
    public List<GameObject> Objects3d = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject ActualSelected;
    public Text MergeText;

    public void add3DtoList()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in ParentOfList) // iterate through all first level children
        {
            if (child.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                Debug.Log($"The child {child.name} is active!");
                ActualSelected = child.gameObject;
                if (Objects3d.Contains(ActualSelected))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Already exist in list");
                }
                else
                {
                    Objects3d.Add(ActualSelected); //add the actual gameobject selected in runtime to list
                }
            }
        }
        MergeText.text = string.Join("\n", Objects3d.Select(obj => obj.GetComponent<Text>().text));
    }
```

**SOLVED,**
**Script for two List:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LIST3DOBJECTS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform ParentOfListCodigo;
    public Transform ParentOfListDesc;
    public List<GameObject> Objects3dCodigo = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> Objects3dDesc = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject ActualSelectedCode;
    public GameObject ActualSelectedDesc;
    public Text MergeTextCode;
    public Text MergeTextDesc;
    public Text MergeLists;

    public void add3DtoList()
    {       
        foreach (Transform child in ParentOfListCodigo) // iterate through all first level children
        {
            if (child.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                Debug.Log($"The child {child.name} is active!");
                ActualSelectedCode = child.gameObject;
                if (Objects3dCodigo.Contains(ActualSelectedCode))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Already exist in list");
                }
                else
                {
                    Objects3dCodigo.Add(ActualSelectedCode); //add the actual gameobject selected in runtime to list
                }
            }
        }
        MergeTextCode.text = string.Join("\n", Objects3dCodigo.Select(obj => obj.GetComponent<Text>().text)); //first list, show the code (name), of the children gameobject


        foreach (Transform child in ParentOfListDesc) // iterate through all first level children
        {
            if (child.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                Debug.Log($"The child {child.name} is active!");
                ActualSelectedDesc = child.gameObject;
                if (Objects3dDesc.Contains(ActualSelectedDesc))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Already exist in list");
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Objects3dDesc.Add(ActualSelectedDesc); //add the actual gameobject selected in runtime to list
                    
                }
            }
        }
        MergeTextDesc.text = string.Join("\n", Objects3dDesc.Select(obj => obj.GetComponent<Text>().text)); //second list, show the description of the children gameobject
        CleanText();
    }

    private void CleanText()
    {
        var list1 = Objects3dCodigo.Select(child => child.GetComponent<Text>().text);
        var list2 = Objects3dDesc.Select(child => child.GetComponent<Text>().text);
        var zipped = list1.Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => $"{l1}\n{l2}");
        MergeLists.text = string.Join("\n", zipped);
    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean? Using Linq you could e.g. do `var texts = Objects3d.Select(obj => obj.GetComponent<Text>().text).ToList();` Or do you mean you want to get `child.gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text` ?

Comment: @derHugo
I edited my post, I think is a little more descriptive now.
basically what I want to do is: after adding all the gameobjects what I need to the list, I need to get the text component of each gameobject and merge them in a new text variable.
like: MergeText.text = ListIndex1.text + ListIndex2.text + etc;

Comment: but get the text components of what? the child objects you collect in `Objects3d`?

Comment: Correct, I need get the text components of the child objects  what I collect in Objects3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do would be something like e.g.

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var child in Objects3d)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(child.GetComponent<Text>().text);
}
MergeText.text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

or if you want to use `Linq` you could also e.g. do something like

```
MergeText.text = string.Join("", Objects3d.Select(child => child.GetComponent<Text>().text));
```

instead of `""` you can also use a "delimiter" - a separator string like e.g. `" "` or `", "` or `"\n"` etc.

Same thing you could of course also additionally append using the upper method.

---

To your follow up question from the comments

For two lists you could either take the first approach but iterate by index like e.g.

```
for(var i =0; i< Objects3d.Length; i++)
{  
    stringBuilder.Append(Objects3d[i]).Append('\n')
        .Append(otherList[i]).Append('\n'); 
}
```

or you could use the second `Linq` approach and use `.Zip` to "merge" both lists together first I think e.g. like this

```
var list1 = Objects3d.Select(child => child.GetComponent<Text>().text);
var list2 = OtherList.Select(child => child.GetComponent<Text>().text);
var zipped = list1.Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => $"{l1}\n{l2}");
MergeText.text = string.Join("\n", zipped);
```

There might be more elegant solutions though (currently only on my smartphone)

Comment: thats is, this is the solution I wanted, Thanks.
I added the final script to my post.

Comment: @Elfasito glad we figured it out ;)

Comment: Hugo, ca I bother one more time?.
I added a second list to my script, its a copy from the first but with another childs.
Now I want to combine the two list (text components), In a new text var and showing the result text variable like this:
**list1-child1.text + list2-child1.text

list1-child2.text + list2-child2.text**

i tried this:
https://codeshare.io/2KOxOY

but my triying of fuction shows me the content like:
**list1-child1.text + list1-child2.text.
list2-child1.text + list2-child2.text**

Is possible solve that?.

Comment: assuming both lists have the same length you could either use the first snippet iterating instead by index like `for(var i =0; i< Objects3d.Length; i++){ stringBuilder.Append(Objects3d[i]).Append('\n').Append(otherList[i]).Append('\n'); }` or you could use the second `Linq` approach and use `.Zip` to "merge" both lists together first

Comment: Thanks for answer. Im triying with the linq solution.
works but with a problem.
in each iteration the objects that I already added to the list are repeated in the ***MergeText var***
like e.g (Mergetext result):
***first iteration:***
name1 + description1

***second iteration:***
name1 + description1
name1 + description1
name2 + description2
name2 + description2

***third iteration:***
name1 + description1
name1 + description1
name1 + description1
name2 + description2
name2 + description2
name2 + description2
name3 + description3
name3 + description3
name3 + description3

Comment: Well you only do `Objects3d.Add(...)` but you never do `Objects3d.Clear()` .. so your lists probably grow bigger over time with the same objects .. not the fault of Linq but of your lists themselves

Comment: I see the problem.
Im now thinking in take the MergeLists.text and clean the duplicate lines like:
        `CleanText = string.Join("\r\n", MergeText.text.Lines.Distinct());`
but im getting some coding errors.
you think that can be a solution?.
I will try a little more time to solve the problem in this way.
I appreciate your patience and help, thank you.

Comment: No I would rather either before running your `add3DtoList` method call `Objects3d.Clear();` and `YourSecondList.Clear()` or always add a check first before adding the item `if(!Objects3d.Contains(ActualSelected)) { Objects3d.Add(ActualSelected); }`

Comment: for sure im understanding something wrong.
but my lists already have a check `(if)` for prevent adding child's already exists in lists.
the only problem is the textbox (MergeText), showing duplicated lines.

and if I add `objects3d.Clear(),  yourSecondList.Clear()` , the lists become empty. 
I dont want that.
maybe your solution is right, but i'm implementing it of wrong way.
PD: I added my new script problem to my post.

Comment: shouldn't you be calling `CleanText();` at the very end of the method instead of for each new item added to `Objects3dDesc`?

Comment: yes that was a mistake, I moved it to the end of the void.
anyways not change nothing. the two list are updated simustaneosly.

Comment: @Elfasito updated the answer .. maybe my Linq **was** the issue, sorry ;) only typing on smartphone ^^

Comment: Now works like a charm, Thank you so much for everything.
you have a lot of patience haha.

Comment: hehe glad we figured it out again ;) and well I try, as long as the askers also show some effort and try and come up with a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean, you can do this: 
`var TextsList = Objects3d.Select(object => object.GetComponent<Text>()).ToList()` To get all objects text or you can use where to select the component from list where is your value: 
`string text = Objects3d.Where(object => object.GetComponent<Text>() = "your_value");`
It is basic C#